# Clang ошибка при компиляции reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, clang

При попытке компиляции программы на C++ выдаёт ошибку reinterpret_cast from 'const char *' to ... casts away qualifiers...
Как я понимаю, clang ненавидит reinterpret_cast. Как можно решить проблему? (Другие компиляторы не выдают никаких ошибок)

Comment: Мало инфы... но скорее всего Вам надо обернуть reinterpret_cast  в const_cast. Код в студию

Comment: Самую интересную часть ошибки не написали. from 'const char *' to... что?

Comment: @Andrey использовал в своём проекте LazyImporter (https://pastebin.com/axcejCNm), при компиляции в VS всё окей, а clang выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @AnonymousUser192 Это не значит, что проблема в кланге. Может быть это студия недостаточно строго проверяет ошибки. Еще раз, в какой тип вы кастуете `const char *`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat выше скинул исходник
reinterpret_cast from 'const char *' to 'decltype(&VirtualAlloc)' (aka
'void *(*)(void *, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)
attribute((stdcall))') casts away qualifiers
CTX = LPCONTEXT(LI_FIND(VirtualAlloc)(NULL, size...

Comment: Значит Andrey и vsh все правильно угадали. Кланг прав, нужно сначала скастовать в `char *` через `const_cast`, а уже потом делать `reinterpret_cast` (или наоборот, но тогда надо к `decltype(&VirtualAlloc)'` как-то константность добавить).

Answer (score -1):

`reinterpret_cast` не умеет избавляться от константности, которую, предположительно, вы пытаетесь опустить. Либо ошибка в логике преобразования, либо пользуйтесь `reinterpret_cast` совместно с `const_cast`